# how to do my appDelegate coredata supports ios 9 i am using xCode 8

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8, appdelegate

I get a problem actually, I am using Xcode 8, iOS 10 but in my run target I give it 9.1, the problem happens I include CoreData but I need to be functional [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsJ8S.png) with both iOS 9 and iOS 10

I put the image here

[image]

And in this part of the code

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "delete")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

> And in this part are my functions

```
func saveData(){

let  appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as!  AppDelegate
     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newToken =       NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Token_entity", into: context)
    newToken.setValue("85724985724897247ifeifjhadjkfhsauq89r8479138941874193874", forKey: "accessToken" )
    do
    {

        try context.save()
        print("SAVED")

    }
    catch
    {

        ///PROCESS ERROR

    }

} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
 }


  func requestCoreData (){

let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let contex = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let requests = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Token_entity")
    requests.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    do
    {

        let results  = try contex.fetch(requests)
        if results.count > 0
        {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

                if let tokenrequest = result.value(forKey: "accessToken") as? String
                {

                    print(tokenrequest)


                }



            }


        }

    }
    catch
    {

        ///PROCESS ERROR

    }


} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

 }
```

Comment: Don't use `NSPersistentContainer` is you wish to support iOS 9.

Comment: I guess you will have to use XCode 7.3

Comment: But how can i do that ? @rmaddy thanks

Comment: @MoisesLugoA CoreData has been around since iOS 3. `NSPersistentContainer` was added in iOS 10. If people could use CoreData since iOS 3 without using `NSPersistentContainer` then you can too. There must be countless tutorials and examples using CoreData written prior to iOS 10.

Comment: @NikhilManapure Why? The version of Xcode is irrelevant.

Comment: From XCode 8 apple has excluded the `context` from appdelegate and has added `view Context`. So Moises must be getting errors but I am not sure.

Comment: actually i get two functions but i need to be compatible with iOS 9 ...?
below of that

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the iOS 9 and earlier versions of the Core Data code that defaults into the app delegate when you create a project with that option selected is the way the app accesses the ManagedObjectContext. In iOS 10, the context is reached via a new singleton object called the NSPersistentContainer (see the code below from the app delegate in an iOS 10 project created with Core Data). You need to delete any references to persistent container if you're targeting < iOS 10. Here's the iOS 10 variable persistentContainer inside of the app delegate that you need to delete:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  ...

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CustomNumericKeypad")
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {

                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                }
            })
            return container
        }()
}
```

Here's the code necessary to retrieve the context for iOS 9:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator =
        {
            let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
            let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")

            do {
                try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
            } catch {
                let dict : [String : Any] = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey        : "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as NSString,
                                             NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data." as NSString,
                                             NSUnderlyingErrorKey             : error as NSError]
                let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
                print("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }

            return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

The only other thing you have to change is the way you reference the context when saveContext() method in the app delegate when it gets called:

iOS 10 `func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        ...`

iOS 9 `func saveContext () {
        let context = managedObjectContext
        ...`

There is a somewhat straightforward way to implement both ways of obtaining the context so that your code is OS neutral in case you don't want to worry about it if you're switching you're target back and forth between OS 9 and 10 during development. See this [blog post](https://charleswilson.blog/2016/09/09/out-of-context-using-core-data-on-ios-9-3-and-10-0/) for instructions / sample code on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be rather late. I've created a [stack (singleton)](https://github.com/nstein/Essentials/blob/master/Sources/CoreDataStack.swift) that supports iOS versions 8.0 through 10.0. From iOS 10.0 onwards NSPersistentContainer is obviously supported. Please have a look [here](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/09/25/25-core-data-in-ios10-nspersistentcontainer/) for more information.

In you app you can access the read-only and writable contexts irregardless of whether the targets are iOS 8, 9, or 10 like so

```
//Read
let stack = CoreDataStack.shared
stack.viewContext
//fetch operations...


//Write
let stack = CoreDataStack.shared
stack.backgroundContext
//write operations...
```